# Invariant Violation got symbol: mount()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my component which is nothing fancy. But when I import it in the test file and try to load it I get the following error

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import AuditInvestigator from './AuditInvestigator';
import axios from 'axios';

describe('Test Audit Investigator ', () => {
  let wrapper;


  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<AuditInvestigator />)
  })

  it('should contain state', () => {
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
      cancelToken: axios.CancelToken.source()
    })
  })

})
```

If you have any ideas I am open, or you need more info of my code I will provide it.

**EDIT**: AuditInvestigator Content:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import autoBind from 'react-autobind';
import { AuditInvestigatorLayout } from './AuditInvestigatorLayout';
import { reworkRawAllActivityLogsData, reworkUsersData } from '../.././utils/rework-activity-log-data';
import axios from 'axios';

class AuditInvestigator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      autoBind(this);
      this.state = {
        cancelToken: axios.CancelToken.source()
      }
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.requestAllUsers();
    if(this.props.selectedUser.value !== '0') {
      this.props.requestAllLogs({cancelToken: this.state.cancelToken, userId: this.props.selectedUser.value});
    }
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.columnApi;
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    if (this.gridApi) {
      var allColumnIds = [];
      this.gridApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function(column) {
        allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
      });
      this.gridApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
    }
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.state.cancelToken.cancel('operation canceled')
    this.props.requestAllLogsSuccess({logsData: []})
  }

  onUsersSelectChange = (e) => {
    this.props.changeLogsUser(e);
    this.props.requestAllLogs({cancelToken: this.state.cancelToken, userId: e.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AuditInvestigatorLayout
          hideLogsLoader={this.props.hideLogsLoader}
          logsData={reworkRawAllActivityLogsData(this.props.logsData)}
          onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
          usersData={reworkUsersData(this.props.usersData)}
          onUsersSelectChange={this.onUsersSelectChange}
          usersHideLoader={this.props.usersHideLoader}
          selectedUser={this.props.selectedUser}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AuditInvestigator.propTypes = {
  hideLogsLoader: PropTypes.bool,
  logsData: PropTypes.array,
  requestAllLogs: PropTypes.func,
  history: PropTypes.object,
  requestAllLogsSuccess: PropTypes.func,
  requestAllUsers: PropTypes.func,
  selectedUser: PropTypes.object,
  changeLogsUser: PropTypes.func,
  usersData: PropTypes.array,
  usersHideLoader: PropTypes.bool
};

export default AuditInvestigator;
```

Comment: Check this question, seems similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576006/how-to-write-test-cases-using-jest-and-enzyme-for-connected-components-to-my-red

Comment: Are you sure, you are exporting the component in the file `AuditInvestigator`?

Comment: @JohnnyZabala Yep, at the end of the file I got 
"export default AuditInvestigator"

Comment: Probably it would be good to add the content of `AuditInvestigator` to the question.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: @JohnnyZabala I provided the content of Audit Investigator